# How can I do `onErrorContinue` in rxjs

Tags: rxjs

I am trying to resume main stream same like `onErrorContinue` in java reactor core
Java example

```
Flux.range(1, 5)
  .flatMap(n -> (n == 3) ? Mono.error(new Throwable("StoppedError")) : Mono.just(n))
  .onErrorContinue((throwable, o) -> { System.out.println("error with " + o); })
  .subscribe(System.out::println, System.out::println, System.out::println)

// 1
// 2
// error with 3
// 4
// 5
```

How can i do it in RXJS ? Thank you

Until Now already tried

```
Observable.range(1, 5)
  .flatMap(v => v == 3 ? Observable.throwError(new Error("Stopped")): Observable.of(v))
  .subscribe(...logs)
```

Comment: That should be `catchError` https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/catch

Comment: Hi @MoxxiManagarm not working. :-(. stream will stop at 3

Answer (score 0):

You will need to place the `catchError` operator on the inner observable. throwing the error and provide an error value, like `-1`

```
import { of, throwError, range } from "rxjs";
import { map, flatMap, catchError } from "rxjs/operators";

range(1, 5)
  .pipe(
    flatMap(v =>
      (v == 3 ? throwError(new Error("Stopped")) : of(v)).pipe(
        catchError(err => of(-1))
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-dnz4kx?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: But this way i need to handle error on each error throw. i am looking for a solution where from stream if anywhere error will accord one catch function will handle these error. see my java example in that stream all error will go to `onErrorCountinue`

Comment: In my use-case there are few function called from other classes like `.map(class.transform)` I can not go to each class and change code there.

Answer (score 0):

In RxJS continuing after an error is like continuing after completing. It doesn't make semantic sense. Once an RxJS stream errors, it is done. That is the observable contract. `complete()` and `error()` emissions signal the end of an observable.

Without this in the observable contract, operators like `retry` could be disastrous. Also, RxJS streams aren't just dataprocessing and there's no standard for errors after transforming a stream with an operator.

---

#### Catching errors without streams

consider this non-stream error example:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5, i++){
  if(i !== 3) console.log(i);
  else throw(new Error("Failed on " + i));
}
```

Here are two ways to handle this error:

1: try-catch outside the loop

```
try{
  for(let i = 0; i < 5, i++){
    if(i !== 3) console.log(i);
    else throw(new Error("Failed on " + i));
  }
}catch(e){
  console.log(e);
}
```

2: try-catch inside the loop

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5, i++){
  try{
    if(i !== 3) console.log(i);
    else throw(new Error("Failed on " + i));
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e.message);
  }
}
```

If you wanted to try-catch outside the loop and then continue to print 4 and 5, that would be difficult. You'd need to rework the way errors are handled. They'd need a standard that said "This error was thrown in a loop and caused as a direct result of the current value in the loop, therefore it might make sense to continue the loop with the next value."

When you start nesting function calls inside of loops and so on, it becomes an increasingly bizarre tangle to even understand what "continue" after an error even means.

Consider that number 2 handles the error inside the loop and then lets the loop continue on. For number 2, we can throw a new error. Print a different number. Do nothing. We can even break out of the loop early without throwing an error. We have much more control because of where we are in the control flow of the program.

---

In number 1 above, once the loop failed, it was done. The control flow went outside of the loop. If you wanted to mimic a continue, you could start a new loop with the next number as its starting value.

```
function loopToFive(start = 0){
  for(let i = start; i < 5, i++){
    if(i !== 3) console.log(i);
    else throw(new Error("Failed on " + i));
  }  
}

try{
  loopToFive()
}catch(e){
  console.log(e.message)
  loopToFive(4)
}
```

This looks like *catch and continue*, but it's really just *catch and recreate*.

#### Catching Errors with Streams

Streams are just loops done asynchronously so that we can abstract away the time between values. Just like the example above, where you handle an error dramatically changes your ability to decide what happens next.

If you want to catch an error and continue, you can either catch it near the source and manage the control flow or you can catch it later and decide if/what part of the stream to re-create to continue.

Streams have built-in operators to retry, so the options are there. You can re-create `onErrorContinue()` for your case.

Comment: But in my use-case i have data to process, e.g transform, pick, omit some data from objects array. if a single object has any error i don't want to disturb rest of the flow, same idea which stream is offering.

Comment: Same examples above imagine handle 2/4 levels error handling with try-catch or recreate approach. you will get the idea of stream.